# How to wrap text inside a absolute positioned span?

Tags: html, css

the bullet-text will need to be a long string as shown in code it can not be separate words.

overflow auto doesn't seem  to work it clips the bullet text.

Bullet text needs to stay absolute positioned.

I would like to wrap the text to the next line below, how can I do this?

```
<ul>
   <li class="list-item">
      <span class="bullet-text">test_123_test</span>
      <cite>Lorem ispusm dolor sit</cite>
   </li>
</ul>


.list-item {
  list-style: none outside none;
}

.bullet-text {
  background-color:grey;
  left:0; 
  position:absolute;
  width:2em;
}

cite {
  padding-left:10px
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Grundizer/7krMv/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [**`word-wrap: break-word`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap).

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wu79Q/)

```
.bullet-text {
    background-color:grey;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:2em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack, but you can do:

```
<cite><br />Lorem ispusm dolor sit</cite>
```